# My new python gui window opened from another window exits as soon as it opens.How do I fix this

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have written python pyqt code to open a new window with a label from another window on a button click. The issue is ,new window exits as soon as it opens.How do i fix this.

The code I wrote is

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.btn=QtGui.QPushButton('button',self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(display)
        self.show()

class display(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(display,self).__init__()
        self.lab=QtGui.QLabel()
        self.lab.setText("hi")
        self.show()

def main():
    App=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Gui=Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to the `QWidget` object for your second window. Currently when you click the button, the `clicked` signal is fired and it calls `disp1`. That creates the widget, but then it is immediately garbage collected.

Instead do this to keep a reference:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.btn=QtGui.QPushButton('button',self)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.open_new_window)
        self.show()

    def open_new_window(self):
        # creates the window and saves a reference to it in self.second_window
        self.second_window = disp1()

class displ(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(displ,self).__init__()
        self.lab=QtGui.QLabel()
        self.lab.setText("hello")
        self.show()

def main():
    App=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Gui=Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

When passing a function as parameter, maybe it's better not to include the parentheses? Try

```
 sys.exit(App.exec_)
```

Instead of

```
 sys.exit(App.exec_())
```