# Why second python (PyQt4) GUI window shuts down as soon as it opens?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I have written a python code to open a new window on a button click. But the second window shuts down as soon as it opens. Please help me to fix this.

Here is my code :

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.btn=QtGui.QPushButton('button',self)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(displ)
        self.show()

class displ(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(displ,self).__init__()
        self.lab=QtGui.QLabel()
        self.lab.setText("hello")
        self.show()

def main():
    App=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Gui=Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())

main()
```

Comment: Please do not ask 2 times the same, remove this question that is the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252912/my-new-python-gui-window-opened-from-another-window-exits-as-soon-as-it-opens-ho